# Lucene.Net - Return All Documents

Tags: lucene.net

Is there a way to return all documents currently in an Index.

I'm struggling to find a method, I expected it to be straightforward but I cant find anything that does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute a query using `Lucene.Net.Search.MatchAllDocsQuery` as the query instead of building your own.  It'll return hits for all (non-deleted) documents in your index.